# Firefox/Rekonq cannot load audio on soundcloud and bandcamp

Tags: sound, flash

I run kubuntu 14.04 and cannot listen to audio files from soundcloud or bandcamp. f.ex grooveshark or youtube work just fine. I already installed the newest version of flashplugin-installer.

When I want to start a song, it seems to load, but then shuffles through the playlist without playing anything. With Rekonq its the same.

I also removed gnash, since this was mentioned to interfere.

Anybody having the same issues? Any ideas?

Comment: Have you solved this issue? On my ubuntu 14.04 I have the same issue.