# CRITICAL **: gst_app_src_set_size: assertion 'GST_IS_APP_SRC (appsrc)' failed

Tags: sound, firefox, gstreamer

As [reported here before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/502549/firefox-rekonq-cannot-load-audio-on-soundcloud-and-bandcamp), in some cases, at least, `firefox` won't play bandcamp tracks. I have tried to do it when running `firefox` from the command line, both with my default profile, and with a newly created test profile, and the output started dumping the following line over and over again:

```
** (firefox:4678): CRITICAL **: gst_app_src_set_size: assertion 'GST_IS_APP_SRC (appsrc)' failed
```

The same error appears sometimes when firefox crashes (see [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1440904)).

Do you have any idea what is this bug and whether it is really related to the referenced question?

Answer (score -1):

That looks like a problem with GStreamer.

Try to set the `media.gstreamer.enabled` pref to `false` on the `about:config` page.